# Python: Maping multiple strings in a dataframe but only 1 works?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So Im trying to map this gas data together but the CSV out put from my dataframe is only outputting one mapping at a time. Sometimes it hwl, others its lpg? Whats going on?

This is how it is being output

[image]

```
gas_data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\test.csv')
logging.info('Loaded CSV into Dataframe')


def replace_meterexchange():
    gas_data['Work Type'] = gas_data['Work Type'].replace(['dual smets2'], 'EXCHG')
    logging.info('Replaced dual smets2 with EXCHG')

    gas_data['Job status'] = gas_data['Job status'].replace(['completed'], 'COMP')
    logging.info('Replaced completed with COMP')


def replace_payment():
    gas_data['Payment Method Code - REMVE'] = gas_data['Payment Method Code - REMVE'].replace(
        ['Token', 'Smart', 'Card'], 'CR')
    logging.info('Replaced zeno payement types to CR')


def add_location():
    gas_data['Location Code'] = gas_data['Location Code'].replace(
        ['Not known', 'Cellar/Basement', 'Understairs', 'Hall', 'Kitchen',
         'Bathroom', 'Garage/Greenhouse', 'Canteen', 'Cloakroom', 'Cupboard',
         'Domestic Science', 'Front Door', 'Communal Cupboard', 'Kitchen Cupboard',
         'Kitchen under sink', 'Landing', 'Office', 'Office Cupboard',
         'Outside WC', 'Pantry', 'Porch', 'Public Bar', 'Rear of Shop',
         'Saloon Bar', 'Shed', 'Shop Front', 'Shop Window', 'Staff Room',
         'Store Room', 'Toilet', 'Under Counter', 'Waiting Room', 'Outside Box',
         'Other', 'Outside', 'Attic', 'Bedroom', 'Indoors', 'Intake', 'Ladder required',
         'Other not specified', 'Outbuilding/Barn', 'O/S Box with restricted access', 'pole',
         'Sub Station', 'TC Chamber', 'upstairs', 'Under Window', 'Vestry'],
        ['00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17',
         '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '98', '99', '98',
         '98', '98', '98', '98', '98', '98', '99', '98', '98', '98', '98', '98', '98'])
    logging.info('Replaced zeno location text with MDD location codes')

    gas_data['New Meter Model'] = gas_data['New Meter Model'].replace(
        ['G4 (Flonidan)', 'G4 (Secure)', 'G470 (Landis+Gyr)'],
        ['FLN', 'SCM', 'LPG'])
    logging.info('Replaced zeno Meter Models with MDD manufactures codes')


def fln():
    gas_data["New Meter Model"] = gas_data["New Serial Number"].str[-8:].map(
        {"2000": "G4SZV-2", "2100": "G4SZV-2", "1800": "G4SZV-1", "1900": "G4SZV-1"})
    gas_data["New Meter Manufacturer"] = gas_data["New Serial Number"].str[-8:].map(
        {"2000": "FLN", "2100": "FLN", "1800": "FLN", "1900": "FLN"})


def lpg():
    gas_data["New Meter Model"] = gas_data["New Serial Number"].str[-2:].map({"2061": "G470"})
    gas_data["New Meter Manufacturer"] = gas_data["New Serial Number"].str[-2:].map({"2061": "LPG"})


def hwl():
    gas_data["New Meter Model"] = gas_data["New Serial Number"].str[-2:].map({"1914": "BK-G4E"})
    gas_data["New Meter Manufacturer"] = gas_data["New Serial Number"].str[-2:].map({"1914": "HWL"})
    logging.info('Updated meter manufacturer codes and meter models')

def drop():
    gas_data.drop(
        columns=["Comments manually entered"], axis=1, inplace=True)
    logging.info('Dropped "Comments manually entered" column')


def make_csv():
    # Creates the CSV file with a datetime with no index
    gas_data.to_csv('Clean_data_' + datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m%d%Y%H%M%S''.csv'), index=False)
    logging.info('Saved CSV')
```

This is the full code, its mainly just trying to change the CSV data in order to make more senese

Comment: That has not resulted in any changes! I'll show you the full code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the output you shared was printed after running `lpg` function since only the row ending on `2061` was left.

The problem is that `map` maps only rows with the values it can find in the provided dictionary, all the other rows will be empty.

So you need to refill all the values you don't `map`.

For example:

```
def fln():
    df["New Meter Model"] = df["New Serial Number"].str[-4:].map({"2000": "G4SZV-2", "2100": "G4SZV-2", "1800": "G4SZV-1", "1900": "G4SZV-1"}).fillna(df["New Meter Model"])
    df["New Meter Manufacturer"] = df["New Serial Number"].str[-4:].map({"2000": "FLN", "2100": "FLN", "1800": "FLN", "1900": "FLN"}).fillna(df["New Meter Manufacturer"])
```